# Browser Based Functionality for Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Currently for data integration jobs and transformation,user uses Kettle client for performing ETL operations using Spoon GUI.

My question is whether there is a browser based functionality available for Kettle where user can design tranformations & do job integration in the browser itself instead of using desktop PDI application?

Comment: Of course, this is not authorative, but I would say no, there is no such functionality available.

Answer (score 0):

NO there is no such functionality available right now.